# How to show a loading screen while data is processing when I click on a button - React js

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app for a website that integrates with FastAPI and MongoDB. On my website, I ask the user to upload some information, this information will send to FastAPI to be processed and it will take time until the result show. I want to show a loading page when the user clicked on the Estimate button that shows in image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJiLu.png). After that when the result is prepared I want to redirect to the result page.

[image]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this code

```
import React from 'react'
import  { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

const EstimatePage = (props) => {
  const [loadig, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = (data) => {
     setLoading(true)
     //API Call for saving data
     // Got response
     // Check response is success or not
     // If Success
     setLoading(false)
     // Redirect to result component
     return <Redirect to='/result'/>
  }
  return(
    <>
      {loading && (<div>loading...</div>)}
      <form>
        //...Rest of form field
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Estimate</button>
      </form>
    </>
  )
}
```